# CSV file to SQL Table incremental

Tags: sql, csv, reporting-services, bulkinsert

I have an external application which creates CSV files. I would like to write these files into SQL automatically but as incremental.

I was looking into Bulk Insert, but i do not think this is incremental. The CSV files can get huge so incremental will be the way to go.

Thank you.

Comment: In your application, replace the code that writes lines to the CSV file with code that inserts records.

Comment: What makes you think that a bulk insert would not be incremental?  A single insert record does not, in general, depend on any previous inserts (ignoring things like constraints etc.).

Comment: @DanBracuk - Thanks for your comment. The application is an External Application i do not have any control over it. So i will be unable to write to SQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Good thinking, i wasn't 100% sure if it is incremental. I made an assumption that it is not incremental. Are you saying it is Incremental, and you know it for sure?

Comment: To be honest with you, I've never even heard incremental in the same sentence as bulk insert.  Maybe wait for others to chime in; I don't see a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to handle this is to bulk insert the entire CSV into a staging table, and then do the incremental merge of the data in the staging table into the final destination table with a stored procedure.

If you are still concerned that the CSV files are too big for this, the next step is to write a program that reads the CSV, and produces a truncated file with only the new/changed data that you want to import, and then bulk insert that smaller CSV instead of the original one.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a text or csv file with names of all the csv files which you want to load in the table. You can include file path if not repeated. You can do this using shell scripting.
- Then make a temporary table which loads all the csv file names which need to be inserted. Using a procedure.
- Using above temporary table, loop by the number of rows and load it to the target table(without truncating in the loop). If truncate is required then do it before the loop. You can load data to staging if any transformation is required(use procedure for transformation)

We also had the same problem and we were using this method. Recently, we switched to using Python which does all the task and loads data into a staging table. After transformations, it is finally loaded into the target table.